# TeXstudio menu bars and font size is too large

Tags: texstudio

I just downloaded TeXStudio on a new laptop with a 4k screen. I can use the GUI scaling options to change the size of the icons, but the menu font and the menu bars are still far too large for my liking. The text is also too large to work with.

[image: Picture of entire window screen; I don't like how large everything is.]

Answer (score 2):

Menu `Options-> Configure TeX Studio`, then click on the `General` icon to set the menus font size, and on the editor icon to set the font size of the edit window:

[image]

Comment: Right now under general, it says Font Size 8, and under editor, it says Font Size 10. I halved them, and the font size improved, but the tab saying hw4 and the message log area are still far too large to be workable. The size of the font for the line/column counter also has not changed.

Comment: This depends mainly on whether you're far or near sighted.